# posting the wrong form values when jquery ajax posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using twitter bootstrap's v3 modal window to display a star rating form and textarea box form to review a recipe.

When I enter a review in the textarea and select the submit button, it posts the values from the form#rate form and not from the form#form-review form. If I just click on the star rating when in the modal, it works normally. I have the star rating showing up on the recipe detail page and in the modal window (which is the same page since the modal html is at the bottom of the page and only displays onclick). I display it using this line of html: `<div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#star-rating"></div>` I am using the select dropdown example here: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm

I know it is not working because I get a php error back saying there is an index that is undefined, so I checked what params were being posted and noticed it was posting the params from the star rating form when I clicked the submit button for the reviews textarea body form.

I did a var_dump, which outputs:

```
Array ( [return] => /recipes/view/baked-chipotle-chicken-flautas [secure_return] => [limit_by] => member [min] => 0 [max] => 5 [since] => [update_field] => rating [update_with] => )
```

All those indexes are from the star rating form, why would it be posting the inputs/values from the other form? I suspect it has something to do with my jQuery. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<form id="rate" method="post" action="http://misn003.dev/en/?ACT=37"  >
    <div class='hiddenFields'>
    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="6200c45a880fcb40dd881e249b8e5c6fc3234008" />
    <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="18" />
    <input type="hidden" name="entry_type" value="recipe" />
    <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_settings" value="YTo4OntzOjY6InJldHVybiI7czo0NDoiL3JlY2lwZXMvdmlldy9iYWtlZC1jaGlwb3RsZS1jaGlja2VuLWZsYXV0YXMiO3M6MTM6InNlY3VyZV9yZXR1cm4iO2I6MDtzOjg6ImxpbWl0X2J5IjtzOjY6Im1lbWJlciI7czozOiJtaW4iO3M6MToiMCI7czozOiJtYXgiO3M6MToiNSI7czo1OiJzaW5jZSI7YjowO3M6MTI6InVwZGF0ZV9maWVsZCI7czo2OiJyYXRpbmciO3M6MTE6InVwZGF0ZV93aXRoIjtiOjA7fQ==" />
    </div>

    <select id="star-rating">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5" selected>5</option>
    </select>

</form>

$('.rateit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var value = $('#star-rating').val();
    var entry_id = $("input[name=entry_id]").val();
    var xid = $("input[name=XID]").val();
    var form_settings = $("input[name=form_settings]").val();
    var entry_type = $("input[name=entry_type]").val();
    var site_id = $("input[name=site_id]").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: $("#rate").attr("action"), //your server side script
        //data: { id: productID, value: value }, //our data
        data: { value: value, entry_id: entry_id, entry_type: entry_type, site_id: site_id, form_settings: form_settings, XID: xid },
        type: 'POST'
    });
});

$("#review-form").submit(function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var review = $("textarea[name=review]").val();
    var form_settings = $("input[name=form_settings]").val();
    var xid = $("input[name=XID]").val();
    var entry_id = $("input[name=entry_id]").val();
    var entry_type = $("input[name=entry_type]").val();
    var site_id = $("input[name=site_id]").val();

     $.ajax({
         url: $("#review-form").attr("action"), //your server side script
         data: { review: review, entry_id: entry_id, entry_type: entry_type, site_id: site_id, form_settings: form_settings, XID: xid },
         type: 'POST',
         success: function (data) {
             $('#response').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
             $('#review-form').hide();
             $('#review-form-response').html(data);
         },
         error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
             $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
         }
     });
});

<!-- Add Review Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add-review" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">REVIEW THIS RECIPE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                    Rate Recipe: <div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#star-rating"></div>

                    <form id="review-form" method="post" action="http://misn003.dev/en/?ACT=38"  >
                        <div class='hiddenFields'>
                        <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="139c294e6381715e7ee8752753fd080bd4179162" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="18" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="entry_type" value="recipe" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="form_settings" value="YTo1OntzOjY6ImFjdGl2ZSI7czoxOiIxIjtzOjY6InJldHVybiI7czo0NDoiL3JlY2lwZXMvdmlldy9iYWtlZC1jaGlwb3RsZS1jaGlja2VuLWZsYXV0YXMiO3M6MTM6InNlY3VyZV9yZXR1cm4iO2I6MDtzOjg6ImxpbWl0X2J5IjtzOjY6Im1lbWJlciI7czo1OiJzaW5jZSI7YjowO30=" />
                        </div>

                        <p>Enter Review<br />
                        <textarea name="review"></textarea></p>
                        <button id="submit-review">Add Review</button>

                    </form>

                    <div id="review-form-response"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Tried using ID for the elements?

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs in the page and the modal?

Comment: The thing is, it posts from the rateit form, so I don't think putting id's on each input will resolve that, but I am open for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your jQuery selectors aren't specific enough.

```
// simply calling this will result in finding the value of the LAST occurrence of this tag.
var xid = $("input[name=XID]").val();

// this will target the specific form and pull the value from the tag within the form
var xid = $("form#rate input[name=XID]").val();
var xid = $("form#review-form input[name=XID]").val();

// when listening for a submit then you can simply use $(this)
$("#review-form").submit(function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var xid = $(this).find('input[name=XID]');

    // rather than manually building the data: in your AJAX call you should simply serialize()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
}
```